# Making the file location insensitive to where the node command is being run from?

Tags: node.js

The script `src/main/js/script.js` loads a file with a relative location of `../json/file.json` If I run `node src/main/js/script.js` then I get an error saying that the `../json/file.json` cannot be resolved, however if I cd into the directory `src/main/js` and run `node script.js` from there, there's not problem.  How can `script.js` be written such that it does not matter where the script is being run from.  In other words how do I specify that the `file.json` file is located relative to the location of the `script.js` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var location = path.join(__dirname, '../json/file.json');
require('fs').createReadStream(location)
```

Originally it was:

```
require('fs').createReadStream('../json/file.json');
```